# How to delete on cascade on Rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, cascade

I have this DB design:

contracts

- id
- name

allotment

- id
- name
- contract_id

allotments_rooms

- id
- allotment_id
- room_id

- 1 contract has 1 allotment
- 1 allotment has N allotments_rooms

So…

```rb
Contract has_one :allotment, :dependent => :delete_all
Allotment belongs_to :contract
Allotment has_many :allotments_rooms, :dependent => :delete_all
Allotments_Rooms belongs_to :allotment
```

So, when I delete a Contract, the Allotment is perfectly removed, but the allotments_rooms are not.

Why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you use `:dependent => :delete_all`, you destroy dependent records [*without* calling their *destroy* method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference), so they have no chance to destroy their own associated records. Try `:dependent => :delete` instead.

i would also recommend using [the foreigner gem](https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner) if you want to set FK constraints at DB level (though i don't know if it works with rails 2)